Prevent MySqlDataReader from changing format of values
I have code that sends a SELECT query to a MySQL database. I can see in Wireshark that the database returns DateTime values in this format: 2024-09-03 12:01:23. However, when I run this code to display the data, the format is changed to look like this: 03.09.2024 12:01:23. I may also get an error, if there is a date value like 0000-00-00 00:00:00 (and if I did not explicitly add "Allow Zero Datetime=True" to the connection string).
Is it possible somehow to get the values unchanged for each value in each column, just like how the database sent it to my application?
If I use Console.Write(reader.GetValue(i).GetType().ToString())
It says System.String or MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime or whatever, so it seems that it tries to put the values into data types, which then ends in different outputs than what the database actually sent.

Display format usually follows the locale you set in your system.  In this case, probably your locale format is dd-MM-YYYY.

Unfortunately, I believe you are thinking about this the wrong way, and it will be challenging to change your thought process in the space of a few short paragraphs.

If I use Console.Write(reader.GetValue(i).GetType().ToString()) It says System.String or MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime or whatever, so it seems that it tries to put the values into data types

C# is a strongly-typed platform. It MUST use data types, because there is no untyped data. Everything you see in C# has a data type like int, string, datetime, decimal, etc, or some complex combination thereof. Even variables declared with var have types, as well as values stored in variables declared as object. You will do well to pay attention to these types, especially around date and numeric data.
When you are thinking about your data correct, you will WANT the data stored in the appropriate type. Forcing everything to be one "variant" type, or treating everything as a string, is not good.
For this situation, you see two data types:
In the case of System.String, I promise the code is already providing the value unchanged.
In the case of MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime, you're probably seeing the result of calling the ToString() method on the value (since every type provides this method).
If you want to know how the method works, or why it provides a specific output, you should check the method's documentation. But if it works like the regular C# System.DateTime.ToString() method, it's using the default date format on your system. If you need a specific format, you have to tell it:
((DateTime)reader.GetValue(i)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")


Separate from this, 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is not a valid date for any calendar I've seen. It's just a set of digits to match a mask, but that doesn't make it valid. There is no month 0, for example. If you're letting those values get into your data, you should consider that a mistake (NULL would be better here).

Okay, thank you. But is there no way, to get the value of a column in the current row in an byte array, and I just convert it into ASCII to print it, so that also values like 3.141 are not printet 3,141?

Why would you assume MySQL uses ascii? Or stores numbers internally as strings at all (the wire format might, but internally the data is stored on disk in a format that's not human readable). And what if your user comes from a culture that expects 3,141?

It was just an example, i just wanna use it as the database sent it in wireshark with "." And "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" thats because i have an interface, which needs exactly these formats. There will be no users that need different formats

And there is another problem in your solution: I cannot cast to DateTime. It says "Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime" to type "System.DateTime"

How can i even imagine it inside the MySqlDataReader? Are the values already stored in Datatypes like int, string? Or can I somehow get the value as a byte[] without reading a timestamp by date.year, date.month,... is it possible to do like byte[] values = GetContent(index); and then print this array into console as a string? So that i the MySqlDataReader class did not enter its Parse methods, where it splits the "yyyy-mm-dd ..." string/byte[] into year, month and day?

I just need a method, where i have the raw content of the row and column, where i can get its name and content without any intelligence behind which looks up, what kind of datatype this should be and without parsing into other data types

I dont want to lose any separators the database sent me

"I have an interface that needs those formats." Then you MUST specify those formats. The MySQL wire format is not guaranteed to remain static over time, and already mutates the data from how it was stored on disk.

"How can i imagine it inside the MySqlDataReader? Are the values already stored in Datatypes like int, string?" Yes. You can also get the byte arrays, but it will be the result of exporting the int, string, or datetime data as byte arrays.

""Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime" to type "System.DateTime"  You should check the docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/latest/api/data_api/MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime.html This DOES include an explicit cast to DateTime, but the reason the type exists is MySQL is stupid and allows stroring invalid data in DateTime columns. So there is also an IsValidDateTime property you should check.

Frankly, MySQL has not kept up since it's heyday back in 2006. It stagnated for over a decade while other options advanced, and is now kind of backwards compared to options like SQL Server or Postgresql. It's only just starting to move forward again and still has some catching up to do. If I were starting a new project today and needed an open source database, Postgresql would be the clear winner, and it wouldn't be close.
